# Spark: How to translate count(distinct(value)) in Dataframe API's

Tags: count, apache-spark, distinct, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to compare different ways to aggregate my data.

This is my input data with 2 elements (page,visitor):

```
(PAG1,V1)
(PAG1,V1)
(PAG2,V1)
(PAG2,V2)
(PAG2,V1)
(PAG1,V1)
(PAG1,V2)
(PAG1,V1)
(PAG1,V2)
(PAG1,V1)
(PAG2,V2)
(PAG1,V3)
```

Working with a SQL command into Spark SQL with this code:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Log(page: String, visitor: String)
val logs = data.map(p => Log(p._1,p._2)).toDF()
logs.registerTempTable("logs")
val sqlResult= sqlContext.sql(
                              """select page
                                       ,count(distinct visitor) as visitor
                                   from logs
                               group by page
                              """)
val result = sqlResult.map(x=>(x(0).toString,x(1).toString))
result.foreach(println)
```

I get this output:

```
(PAG1,3) // PAG1 has been visited by 3 different visitors
(PAG2,2) // PAG2 has been visited by 2 different visitors
```

Now, I would like to get the same result using Dataframes and thiers API, but I can't get the same output:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Log(page: String, visitor: String)
val logs = data.map(p => Coppia(p._1,p._2)).toDF()
val result = log.select("page","visitor").groupBy("page").count().distinct
result.foreach(println)
```

In fact, that's what I get as output:

```
[PAG1,8]  // just the simple page count for every page
[PAG2,4]
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you need is the DataFrame aggregation function `countDistinct`:

```scala
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Log(page: String, visitor: String)

val logs = data.map(p => Log(p._1,p._2))
            .toDF()

val result = logs.select("page","visitor")
            .groupBy('page)
            .agg('page, countDistinct('visitor))

result.foreach(println)
```

Comment: I get this error --> not found: value countDistinct

Comment: it's a method in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`, import that :), edit done.

Comment: with intelliJ I'have to write the agg/countDistinct command like this .agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct("visitor")) because even if I've imported org.apache.spark.sql.functions it still gives me the same error... anyway this works, but I only get the visitor column and no page column ([2],[3])... what am I missing?

Comment: @Panto, did you add the underline after functions? `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: ops, I didn't type well... now the import works but I still get just one column as result: the visitor one ([2],[3])... and so I can't match page with visitor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77734/discussion-between-panto-and-yijie-shen).

Comment: try:  `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Answer (score 5):

You can use dataframe's `groupBy` command twice to do so. Here, `df1` is your original input.

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy($"page",$"visitor").agg(count($"visitor").as("count"))
```

This command would produce the following result:

```
page  visitor  count
----  ------   ----
PAG2    V2       2
PAG1    V3       1
PAG1    V1       5
PAG1    V2       2
PAG2    V1       2
```

Then use the `groupBy` command again to get the final result.

```
 df2.groupBy($"page").agg(count($"visitor").as("count"))
```

Final output:

```
page   count
----   ----
PAG1    3
PAG2    2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in the newer versions of Spark it is easier. The following is tested with 2.4.0. 
1. First, create an array for sample.

```
val myArr = Array(
      ("PAG1","V1"),
      ("PAG1","V1"),
      ("PAG2","V1"),
      ("PAG2","V2"),
      ("PAG2","V1"),
      ("PAG1","V1"),
      ("PAG1","V2"),
      ("PAG1","V1"),
      ("PAG1","V2"),
      ("PAG1","V1"),
      ("PAG2","V2"),
      ("PAG1","V3")
    )
```

2. Crate a dataframe

```
val logs = spark.createDataFrame(myArr)
    .withColumnRenamed("_1","page")
    .withColumnRenamed("_2","visitor")
```

3. Now aggregation with distinctCount spark sql function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
logs.groupBy("page").agg(
    F.countDistinct("visitor").as("visitor"))
    .show()
```

4. Expected result:

```
+----+-------+
|page|visitor|
+----+-------+
|PAG1|      3|
|PAG2|      2|
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to display the distinct values of a column

```
display(sparkDF.select('columnName').distinct())
```